# Where is the 'Read this post in our app banner' if I dismissed it once?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, mobile-web

I love the new banner...

Well, I did. I once 'tested' the close button on the banner and now I can't open a question in the app any more.

Where is it? How to open a question in the app again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as intended - once you've said you don't want to see it, you won't see it again.

I presume 'Clear history and website settings' in Settings > Safari would reset it, but I haven't tried.

Source: [Release post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254287/233816)

> If you hit the × the banner goes away forever. We store this in localStorage so if you clear your browser's memory we'll lose the setting, but for most people tapping it will mean never seeing the banner again.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It seems it works as intended, but I still think it is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah... disappearing stuff is never good, but I guess, besides testing this out, when else would it be an issue? What would you suggest instead - being a per page cancel would be irritating if you didn't want to see it... (And kind of spoils the point of having a cancel!)

Comment: I think it should go on a less intrusive location, like suggested in the feature request.

Comment: @PatrickHofman fair, but then basically invisible to everyone who doesn't know it's there. Swings and Roundabouts :-)

Comment: You could do that only if dismissed once. Or ask for confirmation.

Comment: I have put in a separate [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254328/245360) for this. Thanks for your help.