# Show the 'Read this post in our app' after dismissal

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mobile-web

This is a follow up from this question: [Where is the 'Read this post in our app banner' if I dismissed it once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254310/245360)

It seems that once you dismissed the `Read this post in our app` banner you can't get it back any more.

From [Launch iOS app from sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254287/245360):

> If you hit the × the banner goes away forever. We store this in localStorage so if you clear your browser's memory we'll lose the setting, but for most people tapping it will mean never seeing the banner again.

I want to do a request. Can either of these options:

- Make the banner less intrusive (place it in the footer) once dismissed;
- Warn the user it can't ever get the setting back and ask for confirmation;
- Provide a way to get the banner back.

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome to see being requested since we went out of our way to not make the banner too annoying, so going a bit overboard on that is a good thing that we can fix.

If this gets more backing I'd love to do something like an exponential decay instead of making the × hide it permanently I'd like if it hid it for a day at first, then a week, then a month, then got the hint and never showed up again.

Even if we don't end up doing this, I think we're going to add "open in app" buttons to questions/answers next to the current "share"/etc buttons under every post, alongside a 'Open in Stack Exchange for [iOS|Android]' at the bottom of the page next to the "Get the app" links.

I'll report back when this has been done.

Comment: Any progress @kasra?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to work on this in a while, but apparently iOS 9 broke how we do deeplinking so I'll need to work on this next week.

Comment: Okay. Looking forward to hear from you. Good luck!

Comment: Well, [it became annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299778/how-to-remove-read-this-post-in-our-app-notification). /cc @PatrickHofman