# "Read this post in our app" notification always appears, even after dismissing it

Tags: bug, user-interface, mobile-web

On any question I browse while on mobile, I see the "read this post in our app" banner.

It appears again even after I dismiss it and reload.

Why can't we just disable this message for ever?

Comment: There should be "x" in the banner. Try tapping it.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping the 'x' in the banner, [as suggested by @ShadowWizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299778/how-to-remove-read-this-post-in-our-app-notification/299780?__=1414030662#comment974278_299778), <s>works only temporary. I'm not sure when the banner comes back (it doesn't immediately after restarting the browser) and it</s> should work, but dismisses it for only one site.

[image]

That link is controlled by the [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP); I don't see it in Safari on macOS, unless I manually change the User Agent to a one resembling Safari on iOS.

That means that when you change the User Agent in your browser on your phone to something that resembles a desktop, you should be set. If it's not possible in the default browser, you can try the following:

- iOS: [Is there a web browser for iOS that will allow me to change the user agent?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/is-there-a-web-browser-for-ios-that-will-allow-me-to-change-the-user-agent)
- Android: [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6233/173792)

Comment: So that's a bug, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254328/show-the-read-this-post-in-our-app-after-dismissal) the banner should never return.

Comment: Or I clear my browser cache too often...