# I closed the "open in app" banner. How can I get it back?

Tags: support, ios-app, mobile-safari, mobile-app

I accidentally clicked on the "close" icon on the "open in app" banner on a Stack Exchange site, and now I can't get it back. As stated in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254287) answer, it's permanently gone.

> If you hit the × the banner goes away *forever*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you quoted has a followup:

> We store this in localStorage so if you clear your browser's memory we'll lose the setting, but for most people tapping it will mean never seeing the banner again.

So just clear the local storage of the browser app (your browser's memory) and you will see the banner again.

Comment: What domain is the data assigned to? Stackexchange.com or the site I closed the popup in. Also, time to scroll through a gigantic non-searchable sorted-by-abstract-data (filesize) list.

Comment: @Jan good question... I'm afraid I don't know. Here on MSE you can comment anywhere with 5 rep, so you can ask Kasra in a comment on his answer. Good luck! :)